# AjaxFileUpload don't flush %windir%\temp\

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2008, ajaxcontroltoolkit, temp

I have a considerable issue, found by hosting several ASP.NET websites (7 ~ 15) with the **AjaxFileUpload** server control of the **AjaxControlToolkit** library (the latest version):

while the control is processing file, temporary files are saved in the system temporary folder (`%windir%\temp`), but it won't flush that after the request is complete.

I don't know if this is a folder permission problem, or an **AjaxFileUpload** bug.

This is the result after 2 years of hosting, a huge stack of temporary folders:

**Top**
[image]

**Bottom**
[image]

There is any way to override that behavior, or i must manually flush that folder every 1-2 months ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use SaveAS() method, you must deleted yourself.

example:

```
protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e) {
    // Save uploaded file to a database table

    e.DeleteTemporaryData();
}
```

more info here: http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2013/04/30/april-2013-release-of-the-ajax-control-toolkit